# Materialising "Friendly" Entities from a disconnected EF5 Context

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application utilising Entity Framework 5 Database First, VB.net, Linq, SQL Server 2008 R2 and a Disconnected Repository Pattern.

I've used the EF5.x dbContext generator to create my POCO's and modified the T4 Template to add various extra bits and bobs, including my INotifiyPropertyChanged Event Raising.

I have various linked tables, and I need to show data in a "Friendly" manner.

As an example, I have the following two tables;

**Colours:**

```
Colour_ID    |  Colour_Name    | Created_By | Creation_Date | Modified_By |  Modification_Date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1         |     Blue        |     1      |    22-01-13   |     1       |       23-01-13
```

**Users:**

```
User_ID  |  First_Name  | Last_Name  |
--------------------------------------
   1     |    Peter     | Gallagher  |
```

In order to show the "Friendly Data" in my DataGrids, I'm pulling in the data, and creating "Friendly Entities" using code such as;

```vb
Using CriticalPathDBContext As CriticalPathEntities = ConnectToDatabase()

        Dim query = (From Colour In CriticalPathDBContext.Colours _
                     .Include(Function(x) x.CreationUser) _
                     .Include(Function(x) x.LastUpdateUser).AsNoTracking.ToList
                     Select New FriendlyColours With {.CreatedBy = If(Colour.CreationUserCode Is Nothing, "", Colour.CreationUser.First_Name & " " & Colour.CreationUser.Last_Name),
                                                      .CreationDate = Colour.CreationDate,
                                                      .CreationUserCode = Colour.CreationUserCode,
                                                      .LastUpdateDate = Colour.LastUpdateDate,
                                                      .LastUpdatedBy = If(Colour.LastUpdateUserCode Is Nothing, "", Colour.LastUpdateUser.First_Name & " " & Colour.LastUpdateUser.Last_Name),
                                                      .LastUpdateUserCode = Colour.LastUpdateUserCode,
                                                      .Colour_ID = Colour.Colour_ID,
                                                      .Colour_Name = Colour.Colour_Name}).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Colour_Name)

        Return New ObservableCollection(Of FriendlyColours)(query)

End Using
```

My problem with the above is, for more complicated connected Entities, this type of query takes a too long.

I've considered using my Buddy Classes to pull in the related data, however in a disconnected pattern, this doesn't work for me.

Obviously, while disconnected, lazy loading isn't an option...

So, my question is... Is there a better way of doing this? For better... Read faster!

Any help would be gratefully received! Maybe I'm missing something obvious!

**Edit...To further explain:**

- I have a query which returns all Products, as well as their
  Components and Product Stock Items...
- There are 4 different sorts of Component lists which are returned, as
  well as a list of Product Stock Items.
- I take each set of Components and Product Stock Items, and fill an
  associated Grid with the results.
- The User is able to add, edit or delete items from the various Components or Product Stock items.

The query is (sorry for the size!);

```
Dim query = (From ProductList In _DBContext.Products _
             .Include(Function(x) x.CreationUser) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.LastUpdateUser) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Colour) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.License) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Pack_Size) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Customer) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Supplier) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.ProductComponents) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.ProductComponents.Select(Function(y) y.ApprovalType)) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.ProductComponents.Select(Function(y) y.Component)) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.ProductComponents.Select(Function(y) y.Component).Select(Function(z) z.ComponentType)) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Product_Stock_Item) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Product_Stock_Item.Select(Function(y) y.Pack_Type)) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Product_Stock_Item.Select(Function(y) y.Product_Sizing)) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Product_Stock_Item.Select(Function(y) y.Units_Of_Measure)) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.ProductType) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.ProductClassification) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.ProductType.ProductDepts) _
             .Include(Function(x) x.Season).AsNoTracking().OrderBy(Function(x) x.Product_Code).ToList
             Select New FriendlyProducts With {.Colour_ID = ProductList.Colour_ID,
                                               .Colour_Name = If(ProductList.Colour_ID Is Nothing, "", ProductList.Colour.Colour_Name),
                                               .CreatedBy = If(ProductList.CreationUserCode Is Nothing, "", ProductList.CreationUser.First_Name & " " & ProductList.CreationUser.Last_Name),
                                               .CreationDate = ProductList.CreationDate,
                                               .CreationUserCode = ProductList.CreationUserCode,
                                               .FriendlyCreationUser = ProductList.CreationUser,
                                               .Cust_Product_Desc_24 = ProductList.Cust_Product_Desc_24,
                                               .Cust_Product_Desc_48 = ProductList.Cust_Product_Desc_48,
                                               .Customer_Code = ProductList.Customer_Code,
                                               .Customer_Name = If(ProductList.Customer_Code Is Nothing, "", ProductList.Customer.NAME),
                                               .Description = ProductList.Description,
                                               .DesignNo = ProductList.DesignNo,
                                               .Gender_ID = ProductList.Gender_ID,
                                               .Gender_Name = If(ProductList.Gender_ID Is Nothing, "", ProductList.Gender.Gender_Name),
                                               .LicenseCode = ProductList.LicenseCode,
                                               .License_Name = If(ProductList.LicenseCode Is Nothing, "", ProductList.License.NAME),
                                               .Pack_Size_ID = ProductList.Pack_Size_ID,
                                               .Pack_Size_Name = If(ProductList.Pack_Size_ID Is Nothing, "", ProductList.Pack_Size.Pack_Size_Name),
                                               .PackagingNR = ProductList.PackagingNR,
                                               .ProductClassification_ID = ProductList.ProductClassification_ID,
                                               .Product_Classification_Name = If(ProductList.ProductClassification_ID Is Nothing, "", ProductList.ProductClassification.ProductClassification_Name),
                                               .Product_Code = ProductList.Product_Code,
                                               .Product_Picture_Path = ProductList.Product_Picture_Path,
                                               .ProductComponentsNR = ProductList.ProductComponentsNR,
                                               .ProductType_ID = ProductList.ProductType_ID,
                                               .ProductType_Name = If(ProductList.ProductType_ID Is Nothing, "", ProductList.ProductType.NAME),
                                               .ProductDept_ID = If(ProductList.ProductType Is Nothing, Nothing, ProductList.ProductType.ProductDept),
                                               .ProductDept_Name = If(ProductList.ProductType Is Nothing, "", (If(ProductList.ProductType.ProductDepts Is Nothing, "", ProductList.ProductType.ProductDepts.NAME))),
                                               .SageDescription = ProductList.SageDescription,
                                               .SeasonCode = ProductList.SeasonCode,
                                               .Season_Name = If(ProductList.SeasonCode Is Nothing, "", ProductList.Season.NAME),
                                               .StrikeOffNR = ProductList.StrikeOffNR,
                                               .Supplier_Code = ProductList.Supplier_Code,
                                               .Supplier_Name = If(ProductList.Supplier_Code Is Nothing, "", ProductList.Supplier.NAME),
                                               .TransfersNR = ProductList.TransfersNR,
                                               .Deleted = ProductList.Deleted,
                                               .LastUpdateDate = ProductList.LastUpdateDate,
                                               .LastUpdatedBy = If(ProductList.LastUpdateUserCode Is Nothing, "", ProductList.LastUpdateUser.First_Name & " " & ProductList.LastUpdateUser.Last_Name),
                                               .LastUpdateUserCode = ProductList.LastUpdateUserCode,
                                               .ProductComponents = If(ProductList.ProductComponents.Count > 0, GetProductComponentsByPrimaryName(ProductList.ProductComponents, "Component"), New ObservableCollection(Of FriendlyProductComponents)),
                                               .ProductPackaging = If(ProductList.ProductComponents.Count > 0, GetProductComponentsByPrimaryName(ProductList.ProductComponents, "Packaging"), New ObservableCollection(Of FriendlyProductComponents)),
                                               .ProductStrikeOffs = If(ProductList.ProductComponents.Count > 0, GetProductComponentsByPrimaryName(ProductList.ProductComponents, "Strike Off"), New ObservableCollection(Of FriendlyProductComponents)),
                                               .ProductTransfers = If(ProductList.ProductComponents.Count > 0, GetProductComponentsByPrimaryName(ProductList.ProductComponents, "Transfers"), New ObservableCollection(Of FriendlyProductComponents)),
                                               .ProductStockItems = If(ProductList.Product_Stock_Item.Count > 0, GetProductStockItems(ProductList.Product_Stock_Item), New ObservableCollection(Of FriendlyProductStockItems))
                                               }).Where(Function(x) x.Deleted = False Or x.Deleted Is Nothing)
```

Where `GetProductComponentsByPrimaryName` calls a function which simply filters the Components by their type and returns a Friendly ObservableCollection.

So each related Set of Components and Product Stock Items is returned as an ObservableCollection, which I can interact with...

Sorry about the long post!

**EDIT - 08-03-13:**

I have not resolved this issue above, but I have managed to persuade the client that they shouldn't be retrieving all the results and then relying on the User to filter afterwards.

This also led me to rejig my Filtering routines so that the Filtering is performed on the database, rather than locally.
Both of these two factors mean the query below now functions at a reasonable speed.

I tried filling my entities manually, but this took far longer than the query which Linq produced for me.

One of these days perhaps I'll revisit this problem to see what I can learn. But for now, I've sidestepped it!

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure that does this same query and return the results as a new entity type or as FriendlyColours if you can swing it.  You are right, doing it like this is a hog.  Not sure what else I can add.

Comment: @Trey... Thanks very much for the reply... I've updated my OP to give a bit more detail.... I'm not sure that an SP can work here... If it can, I'd love to know the methodology!

Comment: The includes will kill you. A few is okay but so many just kills the perf of the resulting sql. As per my twitter comment, i agree with Trey. you should definitely consider a sproc if possible. But the issue is, are the predicates dynamic or are you always filtering on the same fields?

Comment: Ah, just dawned on me this must be a desktop application not web.  Wondered why was VB.  Lol.

Comment: Asp, consider projection or db views. Do you really need graphs or just combine fields from different tables/entities?

Comment: I keep looking and having more thoughts. I just noticed a ToList before the filtering in the first query. Th filter will happen in memory after the db execution. Have you done any db profiling?

Comment: Been ages since done this but I think you need a load sequence at launch.  What this is I assume.  Break it up into multiple separate queries to load in all the parts, this will be much faster than trying to make it figure it all out at once.

Comment: Hey @JulieLerman and Trey... Thanks ever so much for the comments... Sorry for the brief delay... I'm working on GMT here of course!

Comment: All comments seem to point towards using an Sproc here. Then stitching together the results in code, rather than relying on EF to do this for  me. I did some profiling when I wrote the query, and this seemed to be as efficient as possible using the methodology above. Either way, it's a horrible query!

Comment: @JulieLerman I only really need to combine the fields here. I don't need all the related entities, aside from the `Component` and `ProductStockItem` which of course populate their own Grid's. This data is shown live, so the user can click a Product, and see all it's components immediately, rather than waiting for another jump to the database.... I hope this helps!

Comment: @JulieLerman My filters are dynamic. I have a fixed set of filters, but I may not use them at once, so I filter the data after it's been fetched using a collection of predicates, which I know is highly innefecient, but I couldn't figure out another way to have dynamic filters using EF!

Answer (score 1):

That Query will result in a massive amount of data over the wire. You should probably start by projecting to entities that only contains the data you need. Maybe that won't help here though depending on you data needs.

SQL is usually blazing fast at running simple queries so you could try to load each collection seperately and then Stich the entities toghether in code. This will grately reduce the amount of data transfared.

To explain why joining like this will kill your performance here is a simple example:

In my test database I have three tables with very little data but you should still see the pattern.

**First the individual queries**

```
SELECT *  FROM [OPath-dev].[dbo].[Groups] g

1;Hästhovarna;nzb5x50vibb;0;NULL;NULL;0
```

One single row. 39 characters according to notepad++

```
SELECT * FROM [OPath-dev].[dbo].[GroupMemberships]

1;1;1
2;1;0
```

Two rows. 12 characters

```
SELECT * FROM [OPath-dev].[dbo].[Blogs] where id > 5
```

3 rows with the fields;

- Title;
- Intro;
- Body;
- PublishDate;
- Created;
- CreatorIP;
- Creator;
- Edited;
- Editor;
- EditorIP

at 5907 characters

**Joining the two simple tables**

```
  SELECT *
  FROM [OPath-dev].[dbo].[Groups] g
  JOIN [OPath-dev].[dbo].[GroupMemberships] gm on gm.GroupId = g.Id

1;Hästhovarna;nzb5x50vibb;0;NULL;NULL;0;1;1;1
1;Hästhovarna;nzb5x50vibb;0;NULL;NULL;0;2;1;0
```

The length is now 96 characters. If running these two in separate queries it would be 39 + 12 = 51 (Which probably is faster because the small difference).

**Joining all three tables**

```
SELECT *
  FROM [OPath-dev].[dbo].[Groups] g
  JOIN [OPath-dev].[dbo].[GroupMemberships] gm on gm.GroupId = g.Id
  JOIN [OPath-dev].[dbo].[Blogs] b on b.Id > 5
```

The response is 6 rows with the columns:

- Id;
- Name;
- JoinCode;
- IsCompetitionClub;
- SourceSystemKey_SystemKey;
- SourceSystemKey_EntityId;
- SourceSystemKey_HasValue;
- UserId;
- GroupId;
- IsAdministrator
- ID;
- Title;
- Intro;
- Body;
- PublishDate;
- Created;
- CreatorIP;
- Creator;
- Edited;
- Editor;
- EditorIP

The response now is 11954 characters long and we are suddenly paying quite a toll for the joins. Especially if the database is located on the same machine or on a really fast network.

Now this is even a bad example. I have better datasets that would show even worse growth on my other computer. And remeber that you are joining many more columns which will end up in a massive amount of data transfered. If it's a windows application and you are connecting to the database over a WAN that will be a serious problem but even on the local machine you can see that the transfer is not free if you profile.

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough post @Mikael! So, I assume I'm better having a single Sproc that joins the basic data in my query above. Then run single queries (possibly sproc's aswell), to fetch the joined data (such as components etc), and populate my joined collections manually?

Comment: Many times running "flat" queries is faster in my experience. It depends on the how fast the connection between the client and database is. You will have to experiment a bit. Maybe you could even retrive some of the collections later when they are required?

Comment: Hi Mikael... Thanks for the comment. I created an SP for the Friendly Data, that was easy enough... But I couldn't figure out a good way to fill the related collections any faster than EF could do it... In fact far slower... My lack of SQL expertise probably! Any ideas how to go about that?